# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (from) at position 0 (f): The timezone could not be found in the database

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am getting this error

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (from) at position 0 (f): The timezone could not be found in the database

I tried to different methods to solve this error. but not successfully at all.

```
$from = null;
$to = null;

try{
    if ($request->input('from') || $request->input('to')) {

        if ($request->input('from')) {
            $from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->input('from'))->toDateString();
        }
        if ($request->input('to')) {
            $to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->input('to'))->toDateString();
        }

        $validator = Validator::make(
            [
                'from' => $from,
                'to'   => $to
            ],
            [
                'from' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d',
                'to'   => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:from',
            ]
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return \Redirect::back()
                ->with(array('flash_message' => "Please Enter Correct Date Format"));
        }
    }
} catch (\Exception $e)
{
    \Log::debug("Time invalid ");
}
```

issue is fire in here i think `$validator->fails()`

anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: It doesn't like your input. What does `$request->input('from')` contain? Try `Log::info($request->input('from'));` and check the file in `/storage/logs`

Comment: Would you please show us the request values to help you in your problem

Comment: Why do you create $from and $to before validation? You should validate first, if it's valid then now you can create them.

Comment: Then instead of catching the error and have now clue about what happen, just log your whole exception for inspection:
`\Log::debug('Time is invalid', ['exception' => $e]);`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the point in `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->input('from'))->toDateString()` neither, it's basically parsing Y-m-d into a date object then immediately re-converting it into the same string.

Comment: @aynber i tried what you said.`local.INFO: 2021-01-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
        // Validate that the strings have a date format
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'from' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d',
                'to'   => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:from',
            ]
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return \Redirect::back()
                ->with(array('flash_message' => "Please Enter Correct Date Format"));
        }

        // Then after validation, use the string to create date objects
        $from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->input('from'));
        $to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->input('to'));
```